# Getting the array value if the contains keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Basically, I want to scan some array which contain a key word inside, for example:

```
arr = [ {"name":"apple", "count": 2},
{"name":"orange", "count": 5},
{"name":"pear", "count": 3},
{"name":"orange 356", "count": 16},
{"name":"orange fsa", "count": 15},]
```

I would like to get **orange, orange 356 and orange fsa**. I have tried to use different method of Jquery to get my function done.

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.name == "orange"; // tried = and === but no luck 
});
console.log("Filter results:",newArr);
```

and alternative:

```
    var newArr = [];

for(var i= 0, l = arr.length; i< l; i++){
    if(arr[i].name = "orange" ){
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
  console.log("Filter results:",newArr);
```

But it only returns the arr[1] for me, how may I able to get everything contains "orange"?

**Solution:**

```
    var newArr = [];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.eman.indexOf("orange")!=-1; 

});

document.getElementById("123").innerHTML = "Filter results:"+JSON.stringify(newArr);
```

Comment: You named the source array as `Arr` while referring to it in  your function as `arr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

Comment: thanks for the remind, i have modify it , and if it's really a duplicate i should delete this duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String indexOf function, for example, instead of:

```
return item.name == "orange";
```

You do:

```
return item.name.indexOf("orange") != -1;
```

The string indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified search term in a string and it returns -1 if the search term is not found.

Comment: Thanks, i have picked your answer as the right answer is because you are basic on my method to make some small modification which offers me a fine lesson, thank you.

Comment: Enjoy coding and do not forget to enjoy your weekend too.

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) which will `return index` of the search string, if it is greater than *0*, it means `search` string is present in the string.

Try this:

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "apple",
  "count": 2
}, {
  "name": "orange",
  "count": 5
}, {
  "name": "pear",
  "count": 3
}, {
  "name": "orange 356",
  "count": 16
}, {
  "name": "orange fsa",
  "count": 15
}]

var newArr = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item.name.indexOf("orange") > -1;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, i am pleased that you even made a code snippet for me.

Comment: Glad it helped! _Happy coding_